# Xamarin Android - RecyclerView not rendering UI change properly

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that displays various notifications.  One is a friend request notification with an Accept and Reject button.  When Accept or Reject is clicked I update my state, then call notifyDataSetChanged.

This call calls my binding code which then hides the Accept and Reject buttons.  The problem is my Accept and Reject buttons do not get hidden.

Once you touch the recyclerview at all, the UI is updated properly and the buttons are hidden.

So it appears that when I hide some controls that change the height of the row that the recyclerview isn't handling things properly.

I've tried using ForceLayout() on the recyclerview, but that did not work.  How can I get the recyclerview to lay itself out again properly without more interaction from the user?

I've been requested that I show the source code for this:  For brevity I left out business logic because it happens with/without business logic executing.

```
// this is part of my viewholder its the click event for accept
private async void OnClickAcceptRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // update object state here...
    // now get it to redraw
     m_fragNotifications.lstNotifications.GetAdapter().NotifyDataSetChanged()

}

// in OnBindViewHolder I grab my item, then test...
if (vwView.CurrentNotification.State != State.Pending)
{ lytButtonsContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; }
else { lytButtonsContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be sufficient. Could you please post your code where you experience issues? Otherwise it'll be difficult to help you much more.

Comment: @Demitran, thanks for getting back to me.  I updated to show you the source code.  Its not much.  I'm assuming its something specific with my phone no one else will ever see, but I figured I'd ask around anyway...